# Is there a way to add both the entire file form and extra data in the same formdata object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, form-data

I know i have seen other questions but this is quite different from them but in a way similar.

I trying to post a file form with only files in it, so i prevent the default form behavior and then submit the form to a url. however if i use

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
formData.append('name','moredata');
```

the server fails to see more data but if its alone it works well

i also know that this will work but i am trying to submit a form using click evvents then adding extra values not from the form...

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(...)
```

So the question is that is there a way to add both the entire file form and extra data in the same formdata object?

Comment: What `console.log(formData)` just after the `formData.apend()` shows?

Comment: BTW (not solving your issue, but...): you can merely write `var formData  = new FormData(this);`!

Comment: The code looks ok, there shouldn't be any problem there. Can you provide a complete example?